# Align <hr> to the left in an HTML5-compliant way

Tags: css, html, standards

Currently, I'm using

```
<hr align="left" />
```

on my HTML5 page, but I've read that the align property was deprecated in XHTML 4.01 and supposedly removed from HTML5. I'd like to be using CSS rather than an inline attribute like this, but when I tried

```
hr{align: left; max-width: 800px;}
```

or `hr{text-align: left;}` or `hr{left: 0;}` or `hr{float: left;}`, it just showed up in the center.

So what should I use instead of the inline attribute above?

Comment: Could you post some more code?

Comment: It wouldn't really help the situation in this case. Stephen and matt's answers were sufficient.

Comment: Ah yeah, they didn't exist when I posted that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're trying to use something in a way that (as Eliezer Bernart mentions.. and apparently that comment with the link to [the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) disappeared) no longer "works that way". You can, as long as you don't mind it being screwy in IE, just set the margin to zero - http://jsfiddle.net/s52wb/

```
hr {
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

A better idea though would be to mimic the HR's old way of doing things by way of CSS without the use of the HR. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/p5ax9/1/ for a demo:

```
p:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}
p:before {
    content: " ";
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The second way is a little too complex for just putting a hr in, for me, but I'll keep it in mind if I use a horizontal line between every paragraph. The first way is perfect though. Thank you.

Comment: first option, with only `margin-left: 0` worked great, thks

Answer (score 54):

One option would be to set the left margin to zero:

```css
hr{max-width: 800px; margin-left:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. I gave Stephen the check since his had other info that might be pertinent to future readers.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know what browsers were used for some above answers, but I found neither `text-align:left` nor `margin-left:0` worked in both IE (11, Standards mode, HTML5) and Firefox (29).

- IE11: `text-align:left` works, `margin-left:0` leaves rule centred.
- FF: `margin-left:0` works, `text-align:left` leaves rule centred.
- So, either use both, *or* I found that `margin-right:100%` works for both!

Comment: `margin-right` is the way to go. I found setting it to `auto` prevented the margin from always extending past the edge of the container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use div tag instead.

```
<div style="border: thin solid lightgray; width: 100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<hr>` tags have `margin-inline-start` and `margin-inline-end` properties set to `auto`, which centers the element horizontally (similar to setting both left and right margins of an element to auto).

To left-align an `hr` tag, you can set `margin-inline-start` to 0:

```
hr {
    margin-inline-start: 0;
}
```

...and you can right-align an `hr` tag by setting `margin-inline-end` to 0:

```
hr {
    margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
hr {
   display: inline;  //or inline-block
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: He's mentioned in his question that this didn't work. (Post edited)

Comment: This actually made a very short vertical line show up instead. Not sure what that's about. But it definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.line {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--itemBorder);
    color: var(--itemBorder);
}
.width100 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.width90 {
    width: 90% !important;
}
.width80 {
    width: 80% !important;
}
.width70 {
    width: 70% !important;
}
.width60 {
    width: 60% !important;
}
.width50 {
    width: 50% !important;
}
.width40 {
    width: 40% !important;
}
.width30 {
    width: 30% !important;
}
.width20 {
    width: 20% !important;
}
.width10 {
    width: 10% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="line width100" />
```

Comment: I like the idea. But definitely overkill, and all the !important can be very destructive.