# HTML5 tag for horizontal line break

Tags: css, html, line-breaks

I did already find a post about using the `<hr>` tag to insert a line break, but when I looked up the tag on the w3 website (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) it says that all attributes of the tag are not supported in HTML5. Obviously I want to make my website HTML5 compatible, so what would be the best way to insert a visible horizontal line?

Thanks

Comment: Use `HR` if it makes sense along with some common sense CSS.

Comment: Just curious, why not just use a simple <div> and in CSS make it 1px or 2px height? That's what I do.

Comment: @frenchie - I'd like to use whatever is the most semantically sound. <div> elements are quite versatile, but if there's an established element for an effect, I'd want to use that first. Thanks though!

Comment: To edit the lay-out of a hr, just give it a class. Then CSS away. I think that's semantically the best way to do this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can still use `<hr>` as a horizontal line, and you probably should. In HTML5 it defines a thematic break in content, without making any promises about how it is displayed. The attributes that aren't supported in the HTML5 spec are all related to the tag's appearance. The appearance should be set in CSS, not in the HTML itself.

So use the `<hr>` tag without attributes, then style it in CSS to appear the way you want.

Comment: It depends of the use of this <hr> tag. It represents a thematic break so this is not the good tag to use if for example you want to separate a title with it's related content.

Answer (score 16):

Simply use  **hr** tag in **HTML** file and add below code in **CSS** file .

```
    hr {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 8px auto;
       height: 0;
       width: 100%;
       max-height: 0;
       font-size: 1px;
       line-height: 0;
       clear: both;
       border: none;
       border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
```

it works perfectly .

Comment: great :) it works like a charm for me. perfect answer

Answer (score 9):

You can make a div that has the same attributes as the `<hr>` tag. This way it is fully able to be customized. Here is some sample code:

#### The HTML:

```
<h3>This is a header.</h3>
<div class="customHr">.</div>

<p>Here is some sample paragraph text.<br>
This demonstrates what could go below a custom hr.</p>
```

#### The CSS:

```
.customHr {
    width: 95%
    font-size: 1px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 1px;

    background-color: grey;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

---

To see how the project turns out, here is a JSFiddle for the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/qmccsc06/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'd like to stick to the most semantically sound solutions for now, at least while I'm still in the learning stages of HTML/CSS. The <div> element seems quite versatile though- kind of like a fallback element if you ever need any custom effects :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using <hr>, you can one of the border of the enclosing block and display it as a horizontal line.

Here is a sample code:

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="title_block">
    <h3>This is a header.</h3>
</div>
<p>Here is some sample paragraph text.<br>
This demonstrates that a horizontal line goes between the title and the paragraph.</p>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.title_block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this old question just because it still shows up in google queries and I think one optimal answer is missing. Try this code:
**use ::before or ::after**

See [Align <hr> to the left in an HTML5-compliant way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724891/align-hr-to-the-left-in-an-html5-compliant-way)